# What's that on Euler's head? Does the head covering shown in Emanuel Handmann 1753 painting signify scholarship?

Tags: mathematicians, euler

This may be borderline off-topic but this is the only place that I can think of ask this particular question.

I've always seen images of [Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) with a "hat" or head covering that is unfamiliar to me.

Is there a name for the head covering shown in Emanuel Handmann 1753 painting of Euler? Does it carry any specific significance of mathematical scholarship?

[image: Emanuel Handmann 1753 painting of Euler] [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Leonhard_Euler.jpg)

Comment: curiously [this portrait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Emanuel_Handmann.jpg) of Handmann also shows a curious head covering

Comment: Presumably because he is not wearing a wig and his head is shaved.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Handmann or Euler?

Comment: The question is about Euler, but the reason may apply to both...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: see https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/3i3i8i/whats_the_deal_with_eulers_hat/ where the head shaved reason is quoted from Florence Fasanelli in the chapter "Images of Euler" in *Leonhard Euler: Life, Work and Legacy*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He wears the head wrap in combination with a silk [banyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banyan_(clothing)).

In the 18th century...

> It was fashionable for men of an intellectual or philosophical bent to have their portraits painted while wearing banyans. [Benjamin Rush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Rush) wrote:
>
> > Loose dresses contribute to the easy and vigorous exercise of the faculties of the mind. This remark is so obvious, and so generally known, that **we find studious men are always painted in gowns, when they are seated in their libraries**[[2]](https://npg.si.edu/exh/franklin/rush.htm).
>
> … [The banyan] was usually paired with a soft, turban-like cap worn in place of the formal periwig.

The fashion was inspired on a style from (exotic) East Asia.